# Implement Custom AuthenticationHandler in CQ5

Tags: osgi, aem

I want to have a remote system to do the user authentication for our CQ5. I'm guessing AuthenticationHandler on a path is the direction to go. If so, how does AuthenticationHandler works in general. And, In CQ5, how I implement a Custom AuthenticationHandler? How do I go about making it an OSGi bundle (or fragment bundle) and install it into CQ5?

If possible, some code sample with OSGi manifest is appreciated.

Comment: @Woodifer, could you please help me [here][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978803/doubts-on-3rd-party-authentication

Comment: could you please help me here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978803/doubts-on-3rd-party-authentication

Answer (score 2):

You can find a description of how the Sling AuthenticationHandler works [here](http://sling.apache.org/site/form-based-authenticationhandler.html).  Also you can take a look at the Sling [FormAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/auth/form/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/auth/form/impl/FormAuthenticationHandler.java) source for an example.  You can see the details of the OSGi configuration in the [POM file](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/auth/form/pom.xml#L57-L93) for the project, under the configuration for the maven-bundle-plugin.

If you just need to check passwords or sync user accounts you can use a [custom CQ5 LoginModule](http://www.wemblog.com/2012/06/how-to-add-custom-login-module-in-cq55.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking into the jackrabbit AbstractLoginModule http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/security/authentication/AbstractLoginModule.html

I have example of a custom solution/fragment bundle that was written, but it has a lot of pieces.  We were implementing stuff from Gigya (social network login).

We have a few other classes that implement the MyAbstractLoginModule.  I can dig in further and get you more examples if you need.  Hopefully this can get you started down the right path.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractLoginModule extends AbstractLoginModule {
    static private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAbstractLoginModule.class);
    protected Session session;
    protected UserManager userManager;
    protected ValueFactory valueFactory;
    protected long tokenExpiration = 7200000L;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
        if (options.containsKey("tokenExpiration")) {
            try {
                this.tokenExpiration = Long.parseLong(options.get("tokenExpiration").toString());
                logger.debug("- Token expiration -> '" + this.tokenExpiration + "'");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                logger.warn("Unabled to parse token expiration: ", e);
            }
        }
        super.initialize(subject, callbackHandler, sharedState, options);
    }

    /**
    * Initiates the login module
    *
    * @param ch
    * @param ses
    * @param map
    * @throws LoginException
    */
    @Override
    protected void doInit(CallbackHandler ch, Session ses, Map map) throws LoginException {
        logger.trace("doInit");

        SessionImpl session = (SessionImpl) ses;

        try {
            this.session = session;
            this.userManager = session.getUserManager();
            this.valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            throw new LoginException("Unable to retrieve principal editor: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
    * Impersonates users
    *
    * @param prncpl
    * @param c
    * @return
    * @throws RepositoryException
    * @throws LoginException
    */
    @Override
    protected boolean impersonate(Principal prncpl, Credentials c) throws RepositoryException, LoginException {
        Authorizable authrz = this.userManager.getAuthorizable(principal);
        if ((authrz == null) || (authrz.isGroup())) {
            return false;
        }
        Subject impersSubject = getImpersonatorSubject(credentials);
        User user = (User) authrz;
        if (user.getImpersonation().allows(impersSubject)) {
            return true;
        }
        throw new FailedLoginException("attempt to impersonate denied for " + principal.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isPreAuthenticated(Credentials creds) {
        return false;
    }
}
```